# 来年受験 - What does taking an exam in the coming year mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, culture

In this doujin that I'm reading, a character - Hinata - comes to his new friend's volleyball practice. When an excited Hinata asks if he could join in their practice, the club members crowd around him, curious as to why he's there (left panel). Among their various questions, one member asks 
来{らい}年{ねん}受{じゅ}験{けん} which I believe translates roughly to "Taking the exam next year?" Considering that this is a middle school volleyball club and they mistake Hinata for an elementary school child, I assume it means that he's asking if Hinata plans to come to their middle school next year. But why is he talking about an exam?

[image]

Comment: Isn't the school private?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how it would matter if the school is private or not?

Comment: Um, let's make sure first if the school is a high school (grade 10-12) or a middle school (grade 7-9). If high school, everyone must take an entrance exam to get in one. If middle school, publicly run ones are exam-free because of compulsory education, but private ones need.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. It's a fictional middle school called 北川第一 (Kitagawa Daiichi) but I don't think the Haikyuu anime or manga ever mentioned it being a public or private school, because the main plot takes place when they're in high school and this doujinshi takes place when they're in middle school, so it's not really something important enough to mention explicitly.

Comment: I guess based on the fact that only private middle schools have entrance exams, that means that this one is private and that's why they're talking about exams to get into the school? If so, I guess that answers my question as to why they're talking about exams for a middle school!

Comment: Hmm... I'm not completely sure how education system goes on in Miyagi (the location of the story), but it has a possibility that this school is a prefectural school, which is of higher tier than ordinary (municipal) middle schools thus needs some exam to screen applicants. (What I'm not totally comfortable with is that the name 第一 is typically municipal one.)

Comment: I think the point is they're just saying he looks young / small, so are assuming he isn't even in the school yet, and from that assumption, ask if he's going to try to enter that school next year. In the next bubble someone asks if he's in elementary school.

Comment: @broccoliforest Can I ask why 第一 strikes you as weird? I don't really know much about the naming of Japanese schools which is why I ask.

Comment: @tamayura Nothing really. Large cities that hold many schools often name each one "town-name nth" in order, so those are named like such are typically municipal schools. Of course there's no hard rule how to name a school, and the plot eventually prevails.